# Fill the BarCode based on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I am trying to print the BarCode based on user input successfully, but the BarCode is not filling correctly. Image Height and Width is increasing/decreasing as user inputs.

Please see the below reference image.[image]

For these, I tried below code.

```
public void fun()
    {
        string barCode = txtCode.Text;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(txtW.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtH.Text)))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
                Font oFont = new Font(@"C:\Users\bojjaiah.thoti\Downloads\IDAutomationCode39\IDAutomation.com Free Code 39 Font\IDAutomationHC39M.ttf", 16);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

            }

            plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
        }
    }
```

Please suggest filling the barcode based on user inputs.

Comment: `Height * 2`, `width * 1.5`. Those 1.5 and 2 values are a guess, you need to calculate them.

Comment: @VDWWD not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID Automation Code 39 font is a font, so as far as I know, you have to set the font size to adjust the scale (so that '16' at the end of your font instantiation needs to adjust to user input). I am not sure if the font is built to scale well by adjusting the vertical and horizontal scale independently.

What you may want to do is prompt the user for width in pixels or inches and their string and calculate what size font to use based on the number of characters in their string. Then calculate how tall that would make the barcode and if that height is larger than the user height requirement, draw a white rectangle across the top of the barcode to snip the bars off at the correct height.

```js
var buttonGen = document.getElementById("btnGen");
buttonGen.onclick = function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("textIn").value;
  var fs;

  // Change the font-size style to match the drop down
  fs = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("selList").selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("test").style.fontSize = fs  + 'px';
  
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
    '*' + // Start Code B
    x + // The originally typed string
    '*'; // Stop Code
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/idautomationhc39m-code-39-barcode" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
      td, th {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 6px;
      }
      .ss {
        font-family: "IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode";
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    &nbsp;Font Size:&nbsp;
    <select id="selList">
      <option value="12">12px</option>
      <option value="14">14px</option>
      <option value="16">16px</option>
      <option value="18">18px</option>
      <option value="20">20px</option>
      <option value="24" selected>24px</option>
      <option value="30">30px</option>
      <option value="36">36px</option>
      <option value="42">42px</option>
      <option value="48">48px</option>
      <option value="54">54px</option>
      <option value="60">60px</option>
      <option value="66">66px</option>
      <option value="72">72px</option>
      <option value="78">78px</option>
      <option value="84">84px</option>
      <option value="90">90px</option>
      <option value="96">96px</option>
    </select>&nbsp;

    <input type="text" id="textIn" value="12587"></input>
    <input type="button" id="btnGen" value="Generate Code 39" tabindex=4/>
    <div id="check"></div><br /><span id="test" class="ss">*12587*</span><br />
    <p>This is a demonstration of use of the Free ID Automation 39 Font.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The same thing I have implemented. and given user inputs to adjust them. If you find better than this solution, I mean calculate font based on height & width suggest reference.

Comment: I'll work on the JS equivalent and update my snippet.